# Consumir API REST y guardar datos en Postgres a través de un CronJob

Tags: nodejs, api, postgresql, requests, cronjobs

Estoy realizando un **cron**, con el cual pretendo obtener los pedidos cargados de una **API REST** que pertenece a una empresa y guardarlo en una base de **Postgres**. El código ya existe y he intento modificarlo para que se adapte a lo que necesito tomando en cuenta mis limitados conocimientos de **Node**.

*A continuación, enseño el código actual:*

```
const request = require('request');
const db = require('./db');
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

// Url con el listado de los pedidos
const uri = 'http://internal-real-magento-alb-cajas-282186269.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/index.php/rest/V1/geoapi/index/remainingDispatchOrdersFilters';
const body = {
    username : "picking",
    password : "Picking1",
    status : "PENDING",
    local : 6
}


var job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
 
/**
 * Consulta los datos, del listado de pedidos, sin los detalles
 * Luego en base a los pedidos obtenidos, consulta sus detalles
 */
request.post(uri, {
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept' : 'application/json'
    },
    body : JSON.stringify(body)
}, async (error, response) => {
    try {
        truncate_tables_db();
        
        if (response.statusCode == 400)
            throw (JSON.parse(response.body));
        
        const _res = JSON.parse(response.body);    
        const pedidos = _res.data;

        for (const pedido of pedidos) {
            const { header, dispatchdata } = pedido;
            insert_pedidos_en_db(header, dispatchdata);                     
        }
        
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(e.message);
    } finally{
        console.log('Proceso finalizado');

    }
});

}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');   

/**
 * Vacia las tablas en cuestion
 */
const truncate_tables_db = async () => {
    try {
        const tables = ['detalle_pedidos', 'pedidos'];
        tables.forEach(async table => {
            await db.query(`TRUNCATE TABLE ${table} CASCADE`);
        });    

        console.log('Truncado correcto');

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}


/**
 * Inserta pedidos en la DB, si se genera algun conflicto hace un rollback
 * y a su vez inserta los detalles, consumiendo otro endpoint
 * 
 * @param pedidoHeader - Cabecera del pedido
 * @param pedidoData - Información de la entrega y datos del cliente
 */
const insert_pedidos_en_db = async (pedidoHeader, pedidoData) => {
    let {
        nro_pedido, cajero , fecha_creacion , local_nombre_zona, estado } = pedidoHeader;

    let { 
        nombre, telefono, entrega_programada_fecha, entrega_programada } = pedidoData

    try {
        // Inserta el pedido
        cajero = `Cajero ${nro_pedido}`;

        await db.query('BEGIN');
        const queryText = `
            INSERT INTO pedidos(num_pedido, supervisor , picker , fecha , sucursal, estado,
            fecha_entrega, hora_rango_entrega, telefono, nombre_cliente) 
            VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10 )`;
        await db.query(queryText, [
            nro_pedido, `Supervisor ${nro_pedido}` , cajero,  fecha_creacion , local_nombre_zona, estado,
            entrega_programada_fecha, entrega_programada, telefono, nombre
        ]);

        // Inserta los detalles
        get_list_detalle_pedido(nro_pedido);
        await db.query('COMMIT');
        
    } catch (e) {
        await db.query('ROLLBACK')
        throw e;
    } finally{
        console.log(`Pedido nro ${nro_pedido} migrado...`)
    }
};


const CATEGORIA = 'CATEGORIA';
const OBS = '--';

/**
 * Consume el listado de detalles por pedido y genera el query para la inserción
 * @param {*} nro_pedido 
*/
const get_list_detalle_pedido = async (nro_pedido) => {
    let uri = 'http://internal-real-magento-alb-cajas-282186269.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/index.php/rest/V1/geoapi/index/salesOrder';
    body['order_id'] = nro_pedido;

    request.post(uri, {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Accept' : 'application/json'
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(body)
    }, async (error, response) => {
        const _response = JSON.parse(response.body);
        const { header, items } = _response.data;
        const { codigo_barras } = header;

        let queryText = `
                INSERT INTO detalle_pedidos(num_pedido, codigo_barra, descripcion, cantidad, categoria, obs) 
                VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) `;

        for (const item of items) {
            let { descripcion, cantidad, sku } = item;

            try {
                 db.query(queryText, [nro_pedido, sku, descripcion, parseFloat(cantidad), CATEGORIA, OBS]);  
             } catch(e) {
                // sentencias para manejar cualquier excepción
                // logMyErrors(e);
             }

            


            console.log(`\tDetalle ${sku} migrado`)
        }

        console.log('==============');
        return;
    });   
}


job.start();
```

Lo que estaria necesitando a continuación es lo siguiente:

1 - Condicionar a los metodos **insert_pedidos_en_db** y **get_list_detalle_pedido** para que guarden los datos solamente si éstos no existen previamente, con lo cual se evita el error de duplicidad.

2 - Existen dos sucursales, y en la imagen solo esta la **número 6**; tambien existe la **2**... Como hago para que el programa busque con ambos números en la variable **local**? Tengo entendido que deberia usar un array o algo similar.

*Adjunto el código db.js*

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const client = new Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'admin',
    database: 'pickup',
    port : '5432'
});

client.connect(function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Conexion establecida");
});

module.exports = client;
```